# Javascript Syntax Query

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to JS, ive found a script which adds a text box below a select field when a specific option is selected (in this instance 'Other'), which works fine, although I want to have the option for the same box to appear if another option is selected aswell 'Friend'. How can I alter the part of the JS which determines this, from my understanding it is this part

```
function showfield(name){
  if(name=='Other')
```

but i don't know the correct syntax to perform this. Im assuming effectively its something like

```
if(name=='Other' or 'Friend')
```

anyhelp would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Here is the current code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name){
  if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<input type="text" name="other" class="text-field" placeholder="Please state.." />';
  else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}

</script>
<form id="quote" class="quote-form">
            <input name="" class="text-field" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input name="" class="text-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" />
            <input name="" class="text-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail Address" />
            <select name="referral" class="select-field" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option selected="selected">Where did you hear about us? (Please select..)</option>
<option value="Checkatrade">Check-a-Trade</option>
<option value="MyBuilder">MyBuilder</option>
<option value="Friend">Referral from a friend (Please state below)</option>
<option value="Other">Other (Please state below)</option>
</select>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: `if (name == 'Other' || name == 'Friend')`

Comment: I think googling for `how to use 'or' operator in javascript` is more simple than posting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
if(name=='Other' || name=='Friend') {
    //do stuff
}
```

The `||` operator in javascript is equivalent to the "or" you are attempting.

Read more on the available operators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Operator_precedence

Comment: Exactly what I needed, appreciate it mate

Answer (score 0):

`if(name=='Other' or 'Friend')` is not correct.

you need to write the variable name a second time like this

```
if (name=='Other' || name=='Friend')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know people have mixed feelings about switch statements, but in this case it works fairly well and is easier to adapt if you need to incorporate other option-specific changes.

```
switch (name) {
  case "Other":
  case "Friend":
    //show input field
    break;
  default:
    //hide input field
    break;
}
```

Also, instead of creating and destroying the input element every time, it might be cleaner to just show and hide it with `display: block` and `display: none`